# Angular-js file upload in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

MY html file: Upload.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="expenses in finalJson.comments">
 <td >
   <div class="image-upload">
     <label for="file-input"> 
      <img src="../images/upload1.jpg" style="width: 20px;"/>{{data.files[0].name}} 
    </label>
     <input id="file-input" type="file" ng-model="expenses.files"  ngf-select accept="*" value=""/>
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

controller : UploadController
I have used this to get the file names after the upload is clicked

var json = JSON.stringify($scope.finalJson.comments);
        console.log(json);

Screenshot:

[image]

When I upload one file its working file, when am adding more then one file I cant get the second file name in the console. Can any one suggest me, how to get many files at once after the upload click was made.

```
[{
    "index": 1,
    "amount": "10",
    "$$hashKey": "object:5",
    "date": "2016-04-11",
    "Category": "58",
    "note": "wdxw",
    "paid_to": "swdw",
    "files": {
        "webkitRelativePath": "",
        "lastModified": 1450934331000,
        "lastModifiedDate": "2015-12-24T05:18:51.000Z",
        "name": "node-js.pdf",
        "type": "application/pdf",
        "size": 182649
    }
}, {
    "$$hashKey": "object:31",
    "date": "2016-04-05",
    "Category": "60",
    "note": "scds",
    "paid_to": "dsad",
    "amount": "20"
}]
```

Comment: While I upload two files I got one file name in console

Comment: @smile refer this for multiple file upload , its working fine http://plnkr.co/edit/oVpgrSWQAcFdV26aVKv7?p=preview

Comment: @siva I need inside the ng-repeat code

Comment: @smile refer this it's working as you expected  https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/vtqavfhf/

Comment: @siva in single button  I upload all files I dont want upload part now In Json console I need, two upload file names

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in ng-repeat

Html code :

```
<div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="fileInput in fileInputs">
        <input type="file" file-model="{{'myFile' + $index}}"/>
        <button ng-click="uploadFile('myFile' + $index)">upload me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model, modelSetter;

            attrs.$observe('fileModel', function(fileModel){
                model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                modelSetter = model.assign;
            });

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope.$parent, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
    $scope.fileInputs = [1,2,3];
    $scope.uploadFile = function(filename){
        var file = $scope[filename];
        console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = "http://httpbin.org/post";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```